# Configuracion servidor con parametro PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT

Tags: php, backend, timeout, phalcon

Tengo el siguiente código en un backend con Phalcon.

```
conn = new \PDO("dblib:host={$data['db']['host']};dbname={$data['db']['dbname']};charset=UTF-8",
    $data['db']['username'], $data['db']['password'],array(
    \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 1000
    )
);
```

El parámetro \PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT me está marcando error "SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes" en el servidor productivo, pero en el servidor de desarrollo si trabaja correctamente.

El motivo por el que agregamos este parámetro es que la conexión tarda 7 minutos y si lo omitimos a los 30 segundos el navegador nos devuelve un error de timeout.

**¿Como se puede configurar el servidor productivo para que soporte el parámetro de la librería PDO de SQL Server igual que el de desarrollo en un servidor PHP?**

Comment: ¿Qué SGBD es y qué versión? Algunos no soportan este parámetro. En ese caso tendrías que pasarlo en el DSN. De todos modos no es normal que una conexión tarde 7 minutos, y **ESE** es el problema que deberías preocuparte por resolver, creo yo.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64). Se hizo así por que así lo solicitaron, obvio que mi alternativa es pasar esa parte pesada de la api a un exe, pero si funciona en nuestro servidor desarrollo debería funcionar tambien en producción. ¿La configuración debería ser en el SGBD o en el servidor Web Linux?

Comment: Pasa el parámetro en el DSN, usando `LoginTimeout`, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179202/5587982).

Comment: Ok, esperamos que eso si lo soporte el servidor web linux, ya que tenga oportunidad voy aplicar este cambio que al parecer se ve viable... muchas gracias...

Comment: Ya nos dirás si así funciona o no.